# having skipXMLDeclaration to 1 still returning the xml header in LibXml

Tags: perl

I google and look like this is the way of getting rid of the XML header, but it didn't work. Can someone please explain what did I do wrong?

```
use XML::LibXML;

$XML::LibXML::skipXMLDeclaration = 1;
my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => $someFilePath);
$dom->toFile('./copied.xml');

My copied.xml is still like this:
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <FirstHeader>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `$XML::LibXML::skipXMLDeclaration` does not work for [`toFile()`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-LibXML/lib/XML/LibXML/Document.pod). It works for [`toString()`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-LibXML/lib/XML/LibXML/Document.pod) though:

```
print $dom->toString();
```

The [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-LibXML/lib/XML/LibXML/Parser.pod) says:

> If skipXMLDeclaration is defined and not '0', the XML declaration is omitted during serialization.

I think it is not clear from the documentation that it should not work with `toFile()`.